# Is there a way to stop IIS instead of disabling it?

Tags: php, iis, localhost, wamp

I want to use wamp to practice php, but I'm currently using IIS because of school. Is there a way to stop IIS for a while so that I can start wamp -> use wamp for like 30 minutes -> stop wamp then continue using IIS? Without disabling IIS. Because when I try to open wamp it will open the IIS localhost and I can't open wamps's phpmyadmin

Comment: You could configure either WAMP's or IIS to use another port (like 8080 instead of 80.) Then you should be able to run both at the same time and you don't need to disable/enable the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can stop it. Just go to "Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager" from your pc. And right side you will find "Manage Server" panel. Just click "Stop" from that panel.
When you need to start again, just "Start" from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try `iisreset /stop` from an elevated console to stop the IIS